# ARIMA MODEL Forecast PLOT in R

Tags: forecasting

I'm currently doing arima forecasting in R and i'm already on the last step of displaying the forecast result but I  am having trouble in displaying the forecast on the graph.

Here is my code:

mydata.arima005 <- arima(d.y, order= c(0,0,5))
mydata.pred1 <- predict (mydata.arima005, n.head =100) 
 plot(d.y)
lines(mydata.pred1$pred, col="blue")
lines(mydata.pred1$pred+2*mydata.pred1$se, col="red")
lines(mydata.pred1$pred-2*mydata.pred1$se, col="red")

So as you can see, I want my graph to show the forecast values in color blue and the confidence interval on red. But this is what I am getting instead.
[image]

So as you can see it's not color coded at all. My code contains no error.
This is a sample of the output I am expecting(got it from youtube)I used the same codes used in this video I got thats why i was wondering why my graph doe not look like this.Hope you could help[image: Expected Output.]

Comment: Maybe expandind plot region will help, something like `plot(d.y, xlim = c(0, 40))`.

Answer (score 0):

The [**forecast**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=forecast) package has some functions for displaying nice plots of the forecasts and prediction intervals.

You would need something like this:

```
library(forecast)
mydata.arima005 <- Arima(d.y, order= c(0,0,5)) 
mydata.pred1 <- forecast(mydata.arima005, h=100) 
plot(mydata.pred1)
```

Or using ggplot2 graphics:

```
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(mydata.pred1)
```